# Triggering code execution in iOS when a framework is loaded

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, static-libraries

How do you get code in a framework to execute when that framework is loaded under iOS?

The application Reveal (http://revealapp.com) uses this technique (combined with listening out for the `UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification` notification).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two possibilities.

1. Use a [`+load` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/load) either in one of your own class or add it on a category on an existing class. For example:

   ```
   @implementation MyClass

   + (void) load
   {
       // Your initialization code
   }

   @end
   ```
2. Use `__attribute__((constructor))` on a function. For example:

   ```
   __attribute__((constructor)) void MyLibraryInitialize(void)
   {
       // Your initialization code
   }
   ```

**Beware**: both methods will execute your code before the `main` function is called.

Answer (score 0):

Reveal uses the +(void)load method on NSObject.